# MVC using composer autoload psr-4 is not worked for me

Tags: php, autoload, psr-4

I'm trying to create a MVC structure and use composer to autoload everything.
But I keep getting this error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Core\Main' not found in /var/www/html/php-framework/index.php:20
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in <b>/var/www/html/php-framework/index.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
```

#### My Structure:

```
Php-framework
 -> src
     -> Core
         -> Main.php  
 -> vendor
 -> composer.json
 -> index.php
```

composer.json file

```
   "psr-4": {
     "App\\":"src/"
   }
```

Main.php file

```
 namespace App\Core;
 Class Main{
     public static function run() {
```

index.php file

```
 require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
 
 App\Core\Main::run();
```

but it show me error

This is d my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: Make sure that the folder name `src` is in lowercase (since your have specified lowercase `src` in the composer.json). If everything is correct, post the content of your composer.json file.

Comment: {
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\":"src/"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup!!

I have resolved the bug myself. I don't know how, but it's working fine.

I followed the steps below:

1. Remove vendor folder
2. Run composer `dump-autoload -o`

Comment: You needn't to remove the `vendor` folder, just do `composer dump-autoload`.

If you've removed the `vendor` folder you might be missing the `packages` installed using `composer` (If any).  Run `composer install` to install them again.

Comment: @InvalidBot I already tried with  `composer dump-autoload` But  its not reflect to the code and then after tried also clear cache command but there was same error displayed...     But anyway thanks for  my attention and comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php file, you must have line like

```
'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
```

If you have not this line try `composer dump-autoload` (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-)

Comment: Yes link is same as your suggestion but still I am not getting any luck.. 
 `'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),`